# Can I use XQD cards on Nikon D810

Tags: nikon, memory-card, nikon-d810

I tried to search some information on this; but unfortunately could not find anything. Could someone help me understand if it is possible to use XQD card in a Nikon D810.

Comment: Have you checked the manual?

Answer (score 3):

According to the manual the D810 has one SD slot and one CF slot. XQD cards are not on the list of tested and approved cards.

From the Nikon site http://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/article/i7rd4235/what-is-xqd-and-why-should-i-use-it.html

> XQD is a media card format that was designed to be a successor to the CompactFlash card. XQD has been adopted by Nikon and was first incorporated into the D4 and D4S and subsequently into the D5 and D500 DSLRs.